# how to correct check checkbox and display if is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, dynamically-generated

i use this code to show some text (`Checked`) when click on 1 or more checkboxes. 
I use the `on` because the checkboxes are dynamically created.

It seems that only IE Edge can not deal with it. I have to click twice on a checkbox to show the `Checked` text. In all other browsers it works immediately. 
Really don't know what is wrong with the code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="3" />

<div class="cb-buttons" style="display:none">Checked</div>

<script>

$(document).on('click','.rafcheckbox',function() {  
  var $checkboxes = $('.rafcheckbox').change(function() {

    var anyChecked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length != 0;
    $(".cb-buttons").toggle(anyChecked);
  });
});

</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5tp4kjm/

Comment: Your issue is most likely due to that you are creating a new change handler, every time a checkbox is clicked.  Duplicate event handlers are going to conflict with each other.  Especially with the usage fo toggle.

Comment: How can i solve this? What should i change in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you already have the delegate for the elements, just change it to a change event handler.
- Inside that logic, toggle the hide class, but force it to have the hide class if no elements are checked.

```js
$(document).on('change','.rafcheckbox',function() {
  $('.cb-buttons').toggleClass('hide', $('.rafcheckbox:checked').length < 1);
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="rafcheckbox" value="3" />

<div class="cb-buttons hide">Checked</div>
```

Comment: I agree it works. But i just figured out that the inline style seems to be the problem. If i use your code with the inline style on `display none`, the problem is still there. But adding class`hide` and put the `display none` in hide solves the problem. At least for Edge

Comment: You can use an inline style as well.  It just doesn't work as nice as the `toggleClass()` does.

Comment: Thnx for the solution. Works great now

Answer (score 1):

Lets try it another way.

```
$(document).on('click','.rafcheckbox',function() {

    if($('.rafcheckbox').is(':checked'))
    {
        //do whatever you want
    }  
    else  
    {
        //do the opposite
    }
});
```